# How to allow duplicates in an eosio::multi_index object?

Tags: multi-index, persistence

How do I create a struct and multi_index table that allow for duplicate records? For example, I have the below struct and multi_index table that is populated via an emplace call that selects a randomly chosen account tg (account) and tgu (account).

```
struct tgb {
  // experimenting with Dapp-generated primary key
  // and blockchain generated primary key
  uint32_t        pkey;     // b-chain generated
  account_name    tg;
  account_name    tgu; 
  uint32_t        timestamp;

  uint32_t primary_key() const { return  breachId; }
  EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(tgb, (pkey)(tg)(tgu)(timestamp));
};

typedef eosio::multi_index<N(tgbs), tgb> tgb_table;
```

The table is being inserted into using the following emplace call:

```
tgb_table tgb(_self, _self);

tgb.emplace(tgu, [&](auto& t) {
    t.pkey                = tgb.available_primary_key();
    t.tg                  = tg;
    t.tgu                 = tgu;
    t.timestamp           = now();
  });
```

If a duplicate tg and tgu are called at the same second, I get an error that most likely a uniqueness constraint was violated.

```
Error 3030000: transaction validation exception
Ensure that your transaction satisfy the contract's constraint!
Error Details:
could not insert object, most likely a uniqueness constraint was violated:
```

However, my expectation was that the "available_primary_key()" method would prevent this error by establishing uniqueness of the record. My workaround has been to create a unique ID in the client script and pass it to the action, but I was hoping that the incrementing "available_primary_key" would suffice.

Is there a way to configure the multi_index table to allow for duplicates?

Comment: Have you looked at the values being output by available_primary_key() in this case? Are they in fact unique?

Comment: I did actually notice this after posting. They are not unique. Am I missing something on the configuration? In the meantime, I'm manually adding a random "breachId" int. Here's what the data looks like:Here's what the data looks like:`{
  "rows": [{
      "pkey": 9893,
      "breachId": 3747,
      "tg": "mbf22",
      "tgu": "uvzhu",
      "timestamp": 1527108383
    },{
      "pkey": 9893,
      "breachId": 4574,
      "tg": "t3l1d",
      "tgu": "dhqzz",
      "timestamp": 1527108383
    },...
`

Comment: It seems the original question is answered: The multi_index is functioning as expected. The problem is duplicates from available_primary_key(). Might be worth a separate question to the community related to that. I don't have an answer to your follow-up question.

Answer (score 4):

I guess your problem might be that you are saving the primary key as uint32_t  but **it has to be a uint64_t**. Because it might be that if you try to save the id (0x00000000) it will cut the last 32 bits (0x0000) and result in a 0x0000. If you try to save a new one then you would expect 0x00000001 which will also be cut to 0x0000.

The available_primary_key() function has the following notation:

```
public inline uint64_t available_primary_key() const
```

I would suggest editing your struct to the following:

```
  struct tgb {
    // experimenting with Dapp-generated primary key
    // and blockchain generated primary key
    uint64_t        pkey;     // b-chain generated
    account_name    tg;
    account_name    tgu; 
    uint32_t        timestamp;

    uint64_t primary_key() const { return  pKey; }
    EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(tgb, (pkey)(tg)(tgu)(timestamp));
  };
```

Further documentation can be found [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference#multi-index).